# Itunes style category type select button

Tags: css

I have noticed on iTunes they have these switch like buttons [image: buttons] it has an active and a normal state. However I am unable to replicate it with css at all. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called [Segmented Controls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW27), here is a tutorial of one made with CSS and HTML: http://www.prcvl.com/articles/segmented-controls

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, i knew i wasn't searching for the right thing haha